# Is there a way to install Ubuntu on a 64-bit x86 SBC with /boot in FAT32 and additional files be added during the installation?

Tags: boot, 16.04

For a SBC (Single Board Computer) I have purchased I must follow very specific instructions to enable booting of a Linux OS by pressing only the power button.

The reason why this is important is that I am physically handicapped and moving from the computer's power button back to my keyboard (in the mere 10 seconds it must be done within) in order to press F12 repeatedly means I am left with extreme breathing difficulty for 4 hours after to 14 hours (and am often knocked unconscious due to the lack of oxygen to my brain because of this issue and my handicap) once having done so.

Here are the instructions one must follow in order to have the system boot by a power button press: https://linuxlink.timesys.com/docs/gsg/gizmo2 but instead I am forced to follow the Ubuntu directions for booting from an SD card, whether I am booting from the MicroSD card slot or the mSATA drive: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromSD

The recent versions of the Ubuntu installer prevents both of the two things which are required in order to have this system boot by only pressing the power button.

I need to know how to install Ubuntu with the /boot partition being on a FAT32 file system partition and install local files (which I have in hand on SD, MicroSD, USB hard drive and USB Flash Drives) into the new system during the installation.

I need to install the Timesys "bzImage-3.12-ts-x86_64" kernel and the "rootfs.tar.gz" files to the system during the installation to allow it to boot by only pressing the power button, otherwise I have to move from the power button to the keyboard within seconds in order to press "F12 repeatedly during the power up. Otherwise, the system will not start.

But I am physically handicapped and having to move that far, that fast is extremely difficult and I need to know how to do the above in order to enable booting by pressing only the power button.

How can the /boot partition be placed on a FAT32 file system partition (which the Ubuntu installer blocks and Ubuntu then blocks if the formatting of that partition is changed after the installation is complete) and how does one go about installing local files to the installation during the install of Ubuntu 16.04?

It works just fine with another distro which has a name which is also a hat and it starts with an "F" and also a distro which has a name which is also a shape and starts with an "A". But I have used Debian and Ubuntu since 2009 when I purchased a Nokia N900 which has a Debian based distro (just as Ubuntu is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by creating another /boot SD which was already FAT32 formatted and copied the Ubuntu EXT4 /boot SD to the FAT32 formatted SD. Then I changed the /etc/fstab to the uuid of the FAT32 SD and installed the rootfs from the timesys build and installed it to my Ubuntu MicroSD from a LiveUSB Ubuntu Mate 16.04. Ubuntu made clear that the FAT32 SD could not be booted, so I had to have it claim itself to be EXT2 while still actually being FAT32, then had to work for many hours to prevent Ubuntu from checking the formatting of the /boot SD upon booting. Not easy, but done.